# Different styles in shiny dropdown

Tags: css, r, shiny

Is it possible to have only part of the text in a shiny drop down in italics.
For example, in the code below I wish the latin part of the name to be in italics.

So each row would appear as:

Red Oak - *Quercus rubra* (11671)

Bur Oak - *Quercus macrocarpa* (2705)

White Oak - *Quercus alba* (2437)

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
                    .item {
                    font-style: italic;
                    }
                    .selectize-dropdown-content  {
                    font-style: italic;
                    }
                    "))
    ),
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput(outputId = "tree"),

    # Print selected tree
    verbatimTextOutput("selection")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output){

  my_list <- reactive({
    data <- c("Red Oak - Quercus rubra (11671)",
                "Bur Oak - Quercus macrocarpa (2705)",
                "White Oak - Quercus alba (2437)"
    )
    my_list <- as.character(data)

  })

  output$tree <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "tree", label = "Select a Tree", choices = my_list())
  })

  # Need reactive function to display variable that holds selected tree
  output$selection <- renderPrint({
        input$tree
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you do `HTML("Red Oak - <i>Quercus rubra (11671)</i>")` for each of the options?

Comment: @r2evans I don't understand why, but when I tried that the `<i>` parts still show up literally

Comment: I wish it were that simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do as follows, but the italic appears only in the list.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    selectizeInput(inputId = "tree", label = "Select a Tree", choices = NULL),

    # Print selected tree
    verbatimTextOutput("selection")
  )
)    

server <- function(input, output, session){

  my_list <- reactive({
    list(`Red Oak - Quercus rubra (11671)` = "red",
         `Bur Oak - Quercus macrocarpa (2705)` = "bur")
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "tree", 
                         choices = my_list(),
                         options = list(render = I(
                           '{
    option: function(item, escape) {
    var splittedLabel = escape(item.label).split(" - ");
    return "<div>" + splittedLabel[0] + " - <i>" + splittedLabel[1] + "</i></div>"
    }
  }'
                         )))
  })

  output$selection <- renderPrint({
    input$tree
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

I don't know whether one can get a style for the selected option. I've seen this technique [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html) (but it took me some time to achieve this result, I find the doc not highly clear).

## EDIT

I have found how to get the style for the selected option as well:

```
  observe({
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "tree", 
                         choices = my_list(),
                         options = list(render = I(
                           '{
    item: function(item, escape) {
      var splittedLabel = escape(item.label).split(" - ");
      return "<div>" + splittedLabel[0] + " - <i>" + splittedLabel[1] + "</i></div>"
    },
    option: function(item, escape) {
      var splittedLabel = escape(item.label).split(" - ");
      return "<div>" + splittedLabel[0] + " - <i>" + splittedLabel[1] + "</i></div>"
    }
  }'
                         ))
    )
  })
```

[image]

## EDIT 2

Perhaps it's better to type the html code directly in the list:

```
  my_list <- reactive({
    list(`Red Oak - <i>Quercus rubra</i> (11671)` = "red",
         `Bur Oak - <i>Quercus macrocarpa</i> (2705)` = "bur")
  })
```

then the Javascript code is straightforward:

```
  observe({
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "tree", 
                         choices = my_list(),
                         options = list(render = I(
                           '{
                           item: function(item, escape) {
                           return "<div>" + item.label + "</div>"
                           },
                           option: function(item, escape) {
                           return "<div>" + item.label + "</div>"
                           }
  }'
                         ))
                         )
    })
```

Comment: @ixodid You're welcome. I've just added an edit to my answer.